# My Html Bootstrap Page Background Video not scaled for mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is my HTML background video page code. The video seems to work fine for desktop. when comes to the mobile it looks not cover for full screen. half of the video only covered for mobile screen.

Html Code:-

```
    <div style="max-width:100vw;height:100vh;overflow:hidden;">
        <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
     </div>
```

CSS Code:-

```
    #myVideo {
    
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      z-index: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is related to the difference in width and height in the video. Try adding a media query so the div that contains the video behaves differently for mobile devices:

```
div {
    width:100vw;
    max-height:100vh;
    overflow:hidden;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
    div {
        max-width:100vw;
        height:100vh;
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for your suggestion. i change this as per your instruction. but still issues there

Comment: same issue or different one? maybe there's more css applied? because it solved it for the code you posted

Comment: same issue happened